# linkage conventions, how to declare qsort

Tags: c++, extern, linkage, qsort

I would like to ask how to declare qsort function from stdlib.h in a different compilation unit and avoid warning about inconsistent dll linkage.

```
typedef int (*FT)(const void*, const void*); //FT has C++ linkage
extern "C"{
    typedef int (__cdecl *CFT)(const void*, const void*);//CFT has C linkage
    void __cdecl qsort(void*p, size_t n, size_t sz, CFT cmp);//cmp has C linkage
}
```

c:\bjarne_exercise_5.cpp(15): warning C4273: 'qsort' : inconsistent dll linkage
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdlib.h(425) : see previous definition of 'qsort'

Comment: Why do you need to (re-)declare `qsort`? Is `#include <stdlib.h>` inadequate somehow?

Comment: no, it is OK, I just would like to know.